# Trouble passing, accessing, or prefilling data - Vue.js / Firestore

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to figure out what I am missing here.  I am trying to pre-fill some data for a user profile page.  That pre-fill data is coming from a Firestore DB collection.  I have been able to prefill existing fields when editing requests, however, I am stumped at the user profile portion.  I've included a link to a video showing what I am seeing.  Also here is an error I am getting:

```
vue-firestore.js?73c3:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: This document (profile) is not exist or permission denied.
    at Object.eval [as next] (vue-firestore.js?73c3:1)
    at next (index.cjs.js?e89a:21048)
    at eval (index.cjs.js?e89a:19341)
```

[Video of my issue](https://youtu.be/ncA9gKehocg)

I believe I am experiencing a problem with one of the following files.  I can supply more info if needed.

Login.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="login">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">


                        <ul class="nav nav-fill nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-login" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-login" aria-selected="true">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-register-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-register" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-register" aria-selected="false">Signup</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-login-tab">
                            
                            <h5 class="text-center">Login Please</h5>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" @keyup.enter="login" v-model="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="login">Login</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-register" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-register-tab">
                            
                             <h5 class="text-center">Create New Account</h5>
                             
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Your name</label>
                                <input type="text" v-model="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your nice name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email"  v-model="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="register">Signup</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    
 
                </div>
           
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import {fb, db} from '../firebase'

export default {
  name: "Login",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data(){
      return {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          password: null
      }
  },
    methods:{
      login(){
          fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
                        .then(() => {
                        $('#login').modal('hide')
                          this.$router.replace('admin');  
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            // Handle Errors here.
                            var errorCode = error.code;
                            var errorMessage = error.message;
                            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                                alert('Wrong password.');
                            } else {
                                alert(errorMessage);
                            }
                            console.log(error);
                    });
      },
      register(){
            fb.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
                .then((user) => {
                    $('#login').modal('hide')
                        // Add a new document in collection "profiles"
                    db.collection("profiles").doc("user.user.uid").set({
                        name: this.name,
                        
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log("Document successfully written!");
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                    }); 
                    
                    this.$router.replace('admin');
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                    alert('The password is too weak.');
                } else {
                    alert(errorMessage);
                }
                console.log(error);
            });
      }
  }
};
</script>


<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

Here is the Profile.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="profile">
      <div class="container">
          
        <div class="intro h-100">
            <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md-6 ml-3">
                    <h3>Profile settings</h3>
                    
                 <p>
                   Change your profile settings here
                 </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                  <img src="/img/svg/profile.svg" width="300" alt="" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="profile-content">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills ml-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">Profile</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"  id="account-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#account" role="tab" aria-controls="account" aria-selected="false">Account settings</a>
            </li>
           
          </ul>

            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active pt-3" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="" v-model="profile.name" placeholder="Full name" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  v-model="profile.phone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  v-model="profile.address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  v-model="profile.postCode" placeholder="Postcode" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="submit" @click="updateProfile" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade pt-3" id="account" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-tab">
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-">
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                              Please use the Reset password email button for reseting the password. The form doens't work currently
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  v-model="account.name" placeholder="User name" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  v-model="account.email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  v-model="account.password" placeholder="New password" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" v-model="account.confirmPassword"  placeholder="Confirm password" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="file" @change="uploadImage" class="form-control">
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="button" @click="resetPassword" value="Reset password email" class="btn btn-success w-100">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            
          </div>

      </div>

    
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { fb, db } from '../firebase';

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  components: {
    
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  },

  data(){
    return {
        profile: {
          name:null,
          phone:null,
          address:null,
          postcode:null
        },

        account:{
            name:null,
            email:null,
            photoUrl:null,
            emailVerified:null,
            password:null,
            confirmPassword:null,
            uid:null
        }       
    }
  },

  firestore(){
      const user = fb.auth().currentUser;
      return {
        profile: db.collection('profiles').doc(user.uid),
      }
  },
  methods:{
      resetPassword(){
          const auth = fb.auth();          

          auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth.currentUser.email).then(() =>  {
               Toast.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Email sent'
              })
          }).catch((error) =>  {
              console.log(error);
          });
      },

      updateProfile(){
          this.$firestore.profile.update(this.profile);
      },
      uploadImage(){
        
      }
  },
  created(){
  }

};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Here is main.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import { fb } from "./firebase";
import VueFirestore from "vue-firestore";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

Vue.use(VueFirestore, {
  key: "id",
  enumerable: true
});

window.Swal = Swal;

const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: "top-end",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000
});

window.Toast = Toast;

window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

Vue.use(VueFirestore);

import "popper.js";
import "bootstrap";
import "./assets/app.scss";

Vue.component("Navbar", require("./components/Navbar.vue").default);
Vue.component("NavAdmin", require("./views/NavAdmin.vue").default);
Vue.component("Requests", require("./views/Requests.vue").default);
Vue.component(
  "ViewBulkRequest",
  require("./views/ViewBulkRequest.vue").default
);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app = "";

fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (!app) {
    new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the only place `profile` is referenced? `this.$firestore.profile.update(this.profile)`

Comment: Hi DigitalDrifter, thanks for your reply.  I have added a screen shot of all the references to 'profile'.  Is this (the image at the bottom) okay?  Thank you again.

Comment: I'm assuming by now that the problem has been fixed? If so please include an answer @prospect101

Answer (score 0):

This was not resolved, we simply switched over to some new code.  Thank you.